# Accepting UpperCase Values using Prompt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get my variables to accept `toUpperCase()` method. I'm not sure on how to go about it.

```
var userName = prompt("whats your name");
var up = userName.toUpperCase();

if(userName === "bob".toUpperCase() || userName === "alice".toUpperCase()) {
    document.write("Welcome "+ userName)
} else {
    document.write("Invalid User Name "+ userName)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean *I am trying to get my variables to accept `toUpperCase` method*?

Comment: Please describe your problem from the business perspective, not the technical view. What should the user be allowed to enter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the upper cased input, that is `up`, in the `if`.

Hope this helps!

```js
var userName = prompt("whats your name")

var up = userName.toUpperCase()

if (up === "bob".toUpperCase() || up === "alice".toUpperCase()) {
  document.body.innerHTML = "Welcome " + up
} else {
  document.body.innerHTML = "Invalid User Name " + userName
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, `document.write` may replace your entire Nodes. So, define a specific target and write the value in it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey just change in if condition userName to up

```
<script>
var userName = prompt("whats your name")
var up = userName.toUpperCase()

if(up  === "bob".toUpperCase() || up === "alice".toUpperCase()) {
    document.write("Welcome "+ up)
} else {
    document.write("Invalid User Name "+ userName)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Again, `document.write` is highly discouraged.

Comment: yea i know, there is no reason to really do document.write